# Revisions marked as keepForever don't retain correct file content

Tags: google-drive-api

The Drive [revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions) documentation states that setting the `keepForever` property on revisions will 'keep the revision forever, even if it is no longer the head revision'.

In accordance with the described functionality, I'm creating a new binary file and setting the `keepForever` property to true. I then upload a new version of the same file and set `keepForever` to true for the new revision. Despite `keepForever` being set on the  first revision, the first revision's file contents do not persist; they are changed to the most recently uploaded revision.

Am I misinterpreting the functionality of `keepForever`, or is the issue I have described not expected functionality i.e. a bug?

Below is the publicly accessible file id and revision ids of a file demonstrating this issue. Revision 1 should have the contents `file 1` and revision 2 should have the contents `file 2`, but both revisions contain `file 2`.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0ByY6IA02pFulZG50RFRFQ2tHWms/revisions


{ revisions: 
   [ { id: '0ByY6IA02pFulOEZWN0dGYlMrOHVVNStPL21kR1N2WnhaSExRPQ',
       modifiedTime: '2016-12-12T01:40:08.744Z',
       keepForever: true },
     { id: '0ByY6IA02pFulNGh1MVFEWmlUM1RtRWUrMkswNjk3Y3pMZ25BPQ',
       modifiedTime: '2016-12-12T01:40:23.356Z',
       keepForever: true } ] }
```

Using the [node.js request](https://github.com/request/request) module this is the HTTP request being made:

```
request({
    method : 'PATCH',
    headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/octet-stream'
    },
    url : `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/0ByY6IA02pFulZG50RFRFQ2tHWms`,
    qs : {
        uploadType : 'media',
        keepRevisionForever : true
    },
    body : fileStream
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating and updating your binary file I think you need to set the file resource property: `keepRevisionForever`. Note this is different than the name of the related revision property: `keepForever`.

The `keepRevisionForever` defaults to `false` and is an optional query parameter that is documented on the V3 Drive APIs [create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create) and [update](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update) requests.

Comment: 1. Where is `keepRevisionForever` in the Drive documentation? I cannot see it listed on the file resource property list, nor the revision resource property list. 2. For any revision that is not the first ever revision, will setting `keepForever` to true keep the revision content forever?

Comment: I have tried supplying `{ keepRevisionForever : true }` as part of the first multipart `application/json` section for the initial file upload but the first version of the file is still being overwritten.

Comment: Apologies for missing it in the docs. My go-to google search didn't locate the page which is amazingly rare for google! https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22keepRevisionForever%22

Comment: I've tried the creation and the update calls again with the `keepRevisionForever=true` query parameter set which sets the file's `keepForever` property to `true` as expected. However the file contents of both revisions are "file 2" as in my original question. Example file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByY6IA02pFulYkpoeDF6MjdtZEk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please add code that demonstrates the problem so that others can reproduce and assist.

Comment: I would have expected two requests and some file1/file2 data each time? It's helpful if you add code that reproduces your problem See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: After created an MCVE I found the API works as expected. I was using the Drive web interface to download and verify the previous revision. It appears that regardless of which revision you choose to download in the right hand "activity" sidebar you always get the most recent revision. I can only correlate this with the webViewLink property which is the same for all revisions, that is, each revision does not have a unique wevViewLink  https://gist.github.com/sabrehagen/e39866a81efd1c5cc656989707748011